# Android RIL Driver How to turn on radio to enable telephone

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I have successfully ported Quectel M95 GSM modem with Android 4.0.4 and I can receive and send sms, make calls, all phone functionality, but to turn on radio I am doing this change in RIL.java file

```
if (cm.isNetworkSupported(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE) == false)
```

I changed this condition to true

```
if (cm.isNetworkSupported(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE) == true)
```

so that my radio hardware may turn on and it works for me but I know its not a proper way, my question is why isNetworkSupported() function ever returns false even I have now ported gsm modem. My second question is how I can enable phone functionality so that my tablet will configure as phone so that this

```
if (cm.isNetworkSupported(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE) == false)
```

returns true.

Comment: If you are going to try to port Android to new hardware, you are likely going to have to be a bit more sophisticated about it than that.  Focus on why the function is reporting information you feel to be untrue - chances are, that report is used elsewhere as well.

Comment: Hi Chris, thanks for your comment, but I don't know why this function is getting false, that's the reason I am asking this from experts just like you..

Comment: Since you are working with a custom build, you have the ability to both examine the actual source code and add debug logging into it so that you can see the execution path that leads to that return value.  Since the you are the only person who has your customized code, you are the only person who can solve this.

Comment: some experts says that by changing some properties of build.prop, boardconfig.mk and device.mk files we can enable mobile radio, I tried but didn't get any success... I am asking that have you any knowledge about these files and its configuration related to mobile radio which works as both wifi + gsm

Comment: Your question is not specific enough for this website.  Since you have not provided the details of what changes you made in your port **the only person who can help you is you**.  This website, in contrast, is a place where someo can ask a  single specific question about a specific, **fully specified** problem which can have a specific answer, and that is not the sort of question you have asked.